# Android MediaRecorder - how to record very short video (stop fails with RuntimeException)

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I want to record videos of various lengths and I'm failing to record a very short one.

When I get to videos under one second of length, `MediaRecorder.stop` starts to fail (*stop failed*) and throw `RuntimeException`.

I am aware that this is documented behaviour, but is there any workaround?

I wouldn't like to go into NDK (and also don't know if it would help).

I also thought of recording a long video and later cutting it. But there could be problem with cutting outside I-frames.

Answer (score 0):

The work around I've seen was to record at least two seconds.

If user stops recording before that, the request is delayed and the stop executed mot before the two seconds are recorded.

Comment: I thought of that, but then I'd need to cut the video somehow. Also it won't work if the user records two short videos in sequence.

Comment: You just call MediaRecorder.stop up to two second later then the user actually pressed the stop key. The Video will be a bit too long for this amount of time. What are the implications for this situation in your apps? Maybe, this is simply tolerable?

Comment: I simply need to be able to record videos of fractions of seconds with as minimum delay as possible. Basically if I'd quickly tap start/stop button, it should produce a set of very very short videos.